# page message access through FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get access to the list of 'discussions' and their messages for a specific page. I see how I could do this with the facebook graph API but I would like to do the same with FQL. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ does not appear to contain any page-related list of discussions table. Am I wrong ?

To be specific, if I try to run the following command:

```
curl -G -d "access_token=XXX" --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT conversations FROM page WHERE page_id = 485257821557724' https://graph.facebook.com/fql
```

I get:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#602) conversations is not a member of the page table.","type":"OAuthException","code":602}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'discussions'? are you talking about the private messages sent by users to the page? If so, accessing those is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean (discussion is the terminology used by facebook) but the link you posted explains how to get them through the graph API. My question is about doing this through FQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unified_*` tables in FQL to achieve this. For example

```sql
SELECT sender,
       recipients,
       body
FROM   unified_message
WHERE  thread_id IN(
           SELECT thread_id
           FROM   unified_thread
           WHERE  folder = 'inbox')
```

With your page access token and  `read_page_mailboxes` permission

Answer (score 0):

for facebook page conversation, u also can try this fql:

```
SELECT message_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id, thread_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0)
```

and your access token must get for facebook page.